# Property [libelle_metier] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: json, laravel

I have a function that displays the select id 'technicien' and he showed his name from table user and there 'metier' 
**techniciens_tables**

```
Schema::create('techniciens', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->boolean('actif')->default(1);
    $table->float('moyenne_avis')->nullable();
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    $table->datetime('deleted_at')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();

});
```

**metier_tables**

```
Schema::create('metiers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('libelle_metier');
        $table->datetime('deleted_at')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**users_table**

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('nom');
        $table->string('prenom');
        $table->string('tel');
        $table->string('mobil');
        $table->boolean('role')->default(0);
        $table->datetime('deleted_at')->nullable();
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**technicien model**

```
public function  user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function metier()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\metier','technicien_metier', 
    'technicien_id','metier_id');

}
```

**metier model**

```
 public function techniciens()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\technicien','technicien_metier', 
    'metier_id','technicien_id');

}
```

**I have this function in my technicien controller**

```
 public function GetTables($id)
{
    $technicien = Technicien::with('user','metier')->find($id);
    $metier = $technicien->metier;
    return [
            'id' => $technicien->id,
            'actif' => $technicien->actif,
            'nom' => $technicien->user->nom,
            'prenom' => $technicien->user->prenom,
            'metier' => $metier->libelle_metier,
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

metier relation is many to many Technicien model. First correct your relation name

```
public function metiers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\metier','technicien_metier', 
    'technicien_id','metier_id');
}
```

then

```
public function GetTables($id)
{
    $technicien = Technicien::with('user','metiers')->find($id);
    $metiers = $technicien->metiers;
    return [
        'id' => $technicien->id,
        'actif' => $technicien->actif,
        'nom' => $technicien->user->nom,
        'prenom' => $technicien->user->prenom,
        'metier' => $metiers->pluck('libelle_metier')->all(),
        // or 'metier' => !empty($metiers->first()) ? $metiers->first()->libelle_metier : 'no metier';
    ];
}
```

Comment: "Method plunck does not exist."

Comment: thak you for answer

Answer (score 3):

Here `$metier` is a collection instance, either you loop it using foreach or get the value using Collection method `first` or `pluck` like this

```
public function GetTables($id)
{
    $technicien = Technicien::with('user','metier')->find($id);
    $metier = $technicien->metier;
    return [
            'id' => $technicien->id,
            'actif' => $technicien->actif,
            'nom' => $technicien->user->nom,
            'prenom' => $technicien->user->prenom,
            'metier' => $metier->first()->libelle_metier,
    ];
}
```

OR

```
public function GetTables($id)
{
    $technicien = Technicien::with('user','metier')->find($id);
    $metier = $technicien->metier;
    return [
            'id' => $technicien->id,
            'actif' => $technicien->actif,
            'nom' => $technicien->user->nom,
            'prenom' => $technicien->user->prenom,
            'metier' => $metier->pluck('libelle_metier')->all(), //it will give you an array
    ];
}
```

Details for Collection https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-pluck

Comment: whith the first it shown me one  'libelle_metier' not all off them because in my relation the 'technicien' have many 'metier'

Answer (score 1):

Obviously ur relationship is returning null `$metier = $technicien->metier;` since there is no relationship so you can do:

```
 public function GetTables($id)
{
    $technicien = Technicien::with('user','metier')->find($id);
    $metier = $technicien->metier;
    return [
            'id' => $technicien->id,
            'actif' => $technicien->actif,
            'nom' => $technicien->user->nom,
            'prenom' => $technicien->user->prenom,
            'metier' => isset($metier->libelle_metier) ? $metier->get()->pluck('libelle_metier') : null,
    ];
}
```

Or adjust ur query to fetch only Technicien that has metier  like :

```
$technicien = Technicien::whereHas('user','metier')->find($id);
```

Comment: instanceofkelmendi thanks for your answer but it shown me like this {"id":1,"actif":1,"nom":"tech 1","prenom":"frederic","metier":false} , but i would like to shown the liste of 'metier' of selected 'technicien'

Comment: @chagou2704 yes because there is no metier for that as a result. check updated anser.